# Two navigation bars are extended together when displayed on mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use two Bootstrap 3 navbars, first one is default and the second is inverse. The problem is when I display the page in mobile devices the two are collapsed normally, but when I extend the second navbar both extended together. Also, when I collapse the second both of them are collapsed.

```html
<!--Start NAVBAR 1-->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" style="font-weight: bold; background-color: white;    margin-bottom: 0; margin-top: 0;
border-color: transparent;" role="navigation">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <img src="" class="img-responsive" href="#" style="padding-left:50px;">
    </div>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-center" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <div class="col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-6 text-center">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center">
                <li>
                    <form class="navbar-form" role="search" style="padding-top:15px">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="q">
                            <div class="input-group-btn">
                                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i style="color:#183F66" class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" style="padding-top:10px; margin:0 !important;">
            <li><a href="#" style="color:#183F66"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out" style="color:#183F66"></span> Logout</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" style="color:#183F66"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" style="color:#183F66"></span> username</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
<!--END NAVBAR 1-->
<!--Start NAVBAR 2-->
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <!--  <div class="container"> -->
    <div style="margin-left:5px;margin-right:5px">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="color:white">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("News", "About", "Home", new { Style = "color:White; font:bold" })</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Supervisors", "Contact", "Home", new { Style = "color:White; font:bold" })</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("About SaVeIT", "Contact", "Home", new { Style = "color:White; font:bold" })</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that, your second toggle button has `data-target=".navbar-collapse"` which targets both navbars. Use an `id` on the second collapsible and target it with that, just like in the example below (I use `#bs-example-navbar-collapse-2` here).

```html
<!--Start NAVBAR 1-->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" style="font-weight: bold; background-color: white;    margin-bottom: 0; margin-top: 0;
border-color: transparent;" role="navigation">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <img src="" class="img-responsive" href="#" style="padding-left:50px;">
    </div>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-center" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <div class="col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-6 text-center">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center">
                <li>
                    <form class="navbar-form" role="search" style="padding-top:15px">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="q">
                            <div class="input-group-btn">
                                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i style="color:#183F66" class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" style="padding-top:10px; margin:0 !important;">
            <li><a href="#" style="color:#183F66"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out" style="color:#183F66"></span> Logout</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" style="color:#183F66"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" style="color:#183F66"></span> username</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
<!--END NAVBAR 1-->
<!--Start NAVBAR 2-->
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <!--  <div class="container"> -->
    <div style="margin-left:5px;margin-right:5px">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <!-- Note: data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-2" -->
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-2">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <!-- Note the new id: #bs-example-navbar-collapse-2 -->
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse"  id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-2">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="color:white">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("News", "About", "Home", new { Style = "color:White; font:bold" })</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Supervisors", "Contact", "Home", new { Style = "color:White; font:bold" })</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("About SaVeIT", "Contact", "Home", new { Style = "color:White; font:bold" })</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```